# Selenium ActionChains.perform( ) method overloads CPU

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a simple bot that plays a game online; I can't link the game since it has private access, however the game is not the problem. Since this game is drawn in a html5 canvas I can't use Selenium click on buttons to push them, but I have to use coordinates and ActionChains methods to actually click on them. This wouldn't be a problem per se, but in the moment the perform() method is called the CPU gets overloaded to 100% usage and everything star going really slow. Is it normal? I would like to run multiple instances of this bot, but this problem doesn't let me do it...
Just for info, I run this on a new intel i5-13500, so I don't think it's a CPU problem.

Edit: I found out this problem shows up ONLY in headless browser mode, when launched without the headless it works just fine. Still, I would like to run this in headless browser, if anyone knows how to solve...

Here's the code I'm using to run everything:

```
# Class definition above...

def startBot(self, link):
        options = Options()
        mobile_emulation = { "deviceName" : "iPhone SE" }
        options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
        options.add_argument(self.strings.ignoreCertificateOption)
        options.add_argument(self.strings.noConsolePrintsOption)
        options.add_argument(self.strings.noAudioOption)
        options.add_argument(self.strings.startMaximizedOption)
        options.binary_location = "driver/chrome-win64/chrome.exe"
        options.add_experimental_option(self.strings.excludeSwitches, [self.strings.enableLogging])
        if self.mode == "headless": options.headless = True

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(executable_path = "driver/chromedriver.exe"), options = options)

        self.driver.get(self.link)

        self.actions = ActionChains(self.driver, duration = 40)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 8)

def clickButton(self):
        # PRESS THE "PLAY" BUTTON
        sleep(1.2)

        self.actions.move_to_element(self.fullBody)
        self.actions.move_by_offset(0, 150)
        self.actions.click()
        self.actions.perform() ############## CPU gets overloaded after this line ##############

        sleep(2.2)

# Other methods below...
```

Just to know, self.fullBody is the selenium element for identifying the canvas.